# How to get a value of the selected radio after click with jquery

Tags: jquery

Hi I start my coding road and stuck with something like that:

```
<form>
<input  type="radio" name="liczba" value="1" /> Jedno pokolenie (3 PT)<br/>
<input  type="radio" name="liczba" value="2" /> Dwa pokolenia (5 PT) <br/>
<input  type="radio" name="liczba" value="3" /> Trzy pokolenia (7 PT) <br/>
<form>
<div  id="Generator_Nemuraj" class="button"><br/> <p>Generuj </p></div>
```

And I try to get the value of selected radio with code like that:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#Generator_Nemuraj').click(function () {
        alert("klik");
        var val = $('input:radio[name=liczba]:checked').val();
        alert(val);
    });
});
</script>
```

Help please :)

Comment: Your code is actually working (after you have updated the question with the new div). What is not working? http://jsfiddle.net/XLUpu/1/

Comment: Something tells me OP actually wants to output the text next to the checked radio button since this works fine, like @Sergio said.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Remove `});` after second `alert()` and it will work: http://jsfiddle.net/Q825S/.

Comment: Sorry. In this case your code is working at least in Firefox. What browser are you using and why do you format your code so that first line is mixed with HTML tag?

Comment: Thnx :) But why does it couse a problem ?? I havent get used to this editor yet Sanja.